# Magento 2.0.2 404 not found

Tags: magento, magento2

I host a site in Magento 2.0.2. I give proper permission and mod_rewrite enable in Apache. but my site is loading home page only. All the pages and admin I got 404 not found.

The Frontend page loads while using with index.php. Admin page is not working.

Comment: check http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89125/how-to-fix-magento-2-2-0-0-rc-admin-page-not-found-after-installation/96441#96441

Comment: i tried but its not working for me. Frontend page load while using with index.php. admin is not working

Comment: this is issue with .htacess kindly add in main folder and give the permission

Comment: I already added the .htaccess file and also give 777 permission

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because mod_rewrite is not installed or working on your Apache server.

mod_rewrite is usually installed as part of MAMP but perhaps your magento .htaccess file is not being loaded for some reason.

The first possibility is that if you extracted the archive file on your mac and moved the files using the finder or uploaded them to a mac web server using something like dreamweaver then by default the Mac does not show files starting with a . such as .htaccess and therfore they would not be copied into the web server directory. The solution to this is probably to enable showing hidden files in the finder on the Mac so you can see and copy the files easily. This link shows you how to enable viewing hidden files. 
http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/

The second possibility is how you have configured your http server. You must tell it to allow .htaccess to override settings in a directory. To do this you must have this in your httpd.conf file.

```
<Directory "/your/magento/directory/">
   Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymlinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Obviously replace "/your/magento/directory/" with the actual path to your Magento installation.

Also Put below code:
For Ubuntu edit the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf (here we have an example of /var/www)

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and change it to;

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

then

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Finally during the installation of Magento 2 when you use the web installation setup in your browser, when you get to the Web Configuration section there is an Advanced Options section where you can turn off Apache Rewrites if you can't get mod rewrite to work. That is fine for experimenting but for an actual web store you would really want to get the re-writes working.

**solution 2**
Install Composer. Now I would like you to download Magento 2 zip from `magentocommerce.com/download`, create new **db** in phpmyadmin, extract zip in htdocs folder. Install Magento 2 but do not use localhost use 127.0.0.1 in store URL and admin URL. After successful installation DO NOT run magento.

Now we are going to verify Composer installation, Deploy static content, clear / flush Magento cache and reindex the Magento 2 blocks. To perform all above actions, press WINDOWS KEY + R to open RUN dialog and type “**cmd**” to open Command Prompt.

Type “**cd PATH_TO_YOUR_MAGENTO2_FILES**” to enter in Magento 2 ROOT directory.

Now to verify Composer installation in above directory, type “**composer install**”.

If you get any error in this step, please check your Composer installation
In this step, we are setting up static content to deploy on our Magento store. To perform this, type “**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**”.

If you get any error, check your PHP.EXE and PHP.INI Environment Variable
Clear / Flush Magento cache by typing “**php bin/magento cache:flush**” in CMD.

And finally, to Reindex Magento Static Blocks type “**php bin/magento indexer:reindex**”.

You are done with successful installation of Magento 2.

Comment: I tried your idea. not working.Frontend page is loaded while using with index.php. admin is not working

Comment: For admin, you have to use solution 2 added in above answer.